# Why can't bind WPF built-in commands with Button same way as can with MenuItem?

Tags: c#, wpf

With this XAML:

```
    <DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit">
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut"/>
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

    <WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="3">
        <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" Width="60">_Cut</Button>
        <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" Width="60" Margin="3,0">_Paste</Button>
    </WrapPanel>

    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
  </DockPanel>
```

I can invoke built-in Cut and Paste Commands from MenuItems, but not from Buttons!? What's wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing binding errors?

Comment: Shouldn't it be Command="{Binding ApplicationCommands.Cut}", should it?

Answer (score 0):

These only work if they are inside a `MenuItem` or `ToolBar`.

```
<ToolBar>
    <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" Width="60">_Cut</Button>
    <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" Width="60" Margin="3,0">_Paste</Button>
</ToolBar>
```

Comment: OK, that way works. But is there an explanation?! Why Button must be inside MenuItem or ToolBar?